# Delete backwards contiguous whitespace or contiguous non-whitespace upto beginning of line

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Vim often creates lines with lots of contiguous whitespace, so I'm surprised there isn't an easy way to backwards delete until the end of the previous word. Am I missing something obvious?

```
hello this is a line       |
```

deletes back to here:

```
hello this is a line|
```

or non-whitespace is before the cursor:

```
hello this is a line|
```

deletes back to here:

```
hello this is a |
```

That way I could map a key in insert mode and just back delete words or not-words.

Comment: For your first case you can use `dTe` in normal mode. For the second case try either `db` in normal mode or `Ctrl-W` in insert mode.

Comment: `dTe` doesn't do anything for me when there is whitespace to the left of the cursor. The cursor doesn't move.

Comment: `dTe` should delete backwards any characters (including spaces)  from the cursor until  the letter `e`. The help page is `:help T`.

Comment: Oh sorry, right. I'm looking for a command that can be repeated thoughtlessly, so regardless of the characters in the previous word. Hence I was testing on a random string, without *e* in my case, which is why it didn't do anything. I want to be able to repeatedly hit the keystroke until it reaches the beginning of the line.

Comment: Ok, then you could define a map `nnoremap ds :s/  *$//g<cr>`. Now `ds` will delete trailings spaces in the current line.

Comment: "Vim often creates lines with lots of contiguous whitespace" What?

Comment: When I hit return in many file types a new line is started at the same indentation level as the line above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this function does what I need:

```
function! BackspaceContiguousInsertMode()
python << EOF
import vim  
try:
    line = vim.current.line
    row, deleteto = vim.current.window.cursor
    if deleteto==0:
        vim.current.line = ""
        vim.command("startinsert")
    elif line[deleteto] == " ":
        deletefrom=deleteto
        while deletefrom-1>0 and vim.current.line[deletefrom-1] == " ":
            deletefrom=deletefrom-1
        vim.current.line=line[:deletefrom] + line[deleteto+1:]
        if len(line)-1 == deleteto:
            vim.current.window.cursor = (row,deletefrom+1)
            vim.command("startinsert!")
        else:
            vim.current.window.cursor = (row,deletefrom)
            vim.command("startinsert")
    else:
        eol=deleteto+1 >= len(line)
        if not eol and line[deleteto+1] != " ":
            trailingline = line[deleteto+1:]
            vim.current.line=line[:deleteto+1] + " " + trailingline
            vim.command("normal diw")
            leadingto=len(vim.current.line)-len(trailingline)-1
            vim.current.line=vim.current.line[:leadingto] + trailingline
            vim.command("startinsert")
        elif eol:    
            vim.command("normal diw")
            vim.command("startinsert!")
        else: 
            vim.command("normal diw")
            vim.command("startinsert")

except Exception as e:
    print("Error: {}".format(e))
EOF
endfunction
inoremap <C-b> <Esc>:call BackspaceContiguousInsertMode()<CR>
```

From insert mode (which is where I wanted to invoke it from) I can press `<C-b>` to back delete each word block or whitespace block to the beginning of the line. Given the following line, each time I press `<C-b>` this is what happens:

```
alskdjf       a;sjdf a kjkdjd        |kja sdf
alskdjf       a;sjdf a kjkdjd|kja sdf
alskdjf       a;sjdf a |kja sdf
alskdjf       a;sjdf a|kja sdf
alskdjf       a;sjdf |kja sdf
alskdjf       a;sjdf|kja sdf
alskdjf       a;|kja sdf
alskdjf       a|kja sdf
alskdjf       |kja sdf
alskdjf|kja sdf
|kja sdf
|... (stays on the same line)
```

Answer (score 1):

While vim doesn't ship with a command like this, it ships with commands that are very close to what you want: `ge` and `gE`, look them up in the help. Luckily this means it's trivial to wrap these in the following normal, visual and operator pending mappings:

```
noremap <expr> <leader>e 'h'.v:count1.'gel'
noremap <expr> <leader>E 'h'.v:count1.'gEl'
onoremap <expr> <silent> <leader>e ':<c-u>normal! vh'.v:count1.'gel<cr>'
onoremap <expr> <silent> <leader>E ':<c-u>normal! vh'.v:count1.'gEl<cr>'
```

Obviously map those to whatever you want, personally I have the first one mapped to `<BS>`. The difference between e and E is that they invoke `ge` (moving by `word`) and `gE` (moving by `WORD`) respectively. See `:h word` and `:h WORD` for details on what that means.

These aren't exactly what you asked for: they don't adjust for where we are when we start so e.g. deleting using this operator will change

```
this is a line|
```

to

```
this is a|
```

instead of

```
this is a |
```

You could certainly fix that if you wanted to write a bit more complex vimscript but it's hardly worth if for one space.

The stuff moved over by the operator-pending map will also subtly change depending on the value of `'selection'` if that bothers you.

#### Edit: This is how I would create the exact solution asked for

```
function! s:Backup(mode)
  let str  = a:mode == 2 ? 'g' : ''
  let str .= a:mode ? 'v' : ''

  let at_end = col('.') >= col('$') - 1
  let str .= getline('.') =~ '\%'.(col('.') - !at_end).'c\S' ? 'b' : 'gel'
  let str .= !at_end && a:mode == 1 ? 'oho' : ''

  execute 'normal!' str
endfunction
```

This doesn't delete by itself, but composes with any vim command, such as the  `d`, `y`, `c` operators, and works in all modes as long as you pass the correct parameter. To replicate the mapping used in the askers answer:

```
inoremap <silent> <c-b> <c-o>d:<c-u>call <SID>Backup(1)<cr>
```

And here are bindings for normal, visual, operator-pending mode on `<leader>e`

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>e :<c-u>call <SID>Backup(0)<cr>
onoremap <silent> <leader>e :<c-u>call <SID>Backup(1)<cr>
xnoremap <silent> <leader>e :<c-u>call <SID>Backup(2)<cr>
```

N.B. mappings must be defined in the same script as the function to use `s:` and `<SID>`, otherwise remove those.

Edit 2: fixed the function name :/
Edit 3: adjusted to fix operation when not at end of line. Apparently vim thinks the cursor is in a different place when appending at the end of the line as it does when inserting.

Comment: It's not what I want as you say but thanks for the effort. I actually just posted an answer with what I need.

Comment: @RiazRizvi No problem, those were mostly from my vimrc. I edited to show how I'd implement the full solution if you're intrested, which has the advantage of being usable with any vim command.

Comment: it's more elegant than my answer, so I'll give it to you if it works. I don't understand how to use it though, when I copy the function in my .vimrc with the inoremap mapping, I get an error when I try to invoke it: `UnknownFunction <SNR>2_Backup`. BTW I've burned too many hours on this, so I'm going to wrap it up in a few hours.

Comment: Oops my bad I typed the function name wrong, it should have been prefixed with `s:` (now fixed). the `s:` and the `<SID>` on the mapping arn't necessary for it to work, you could remove the `<SID>`'s instead of adding the `s:` and it will work, they just provide incapsulation. See `:h <SID>` and `:h s:`

Comment: Hmm, this function eats words in front of the cursor, so on the second line in the example in my answer it eats the *k* in front of the cursor.  I'm going to accept my answer, thanks for the effort though.

Comment: Fixed, sorry it took so long to get back to you. Interesting bug that, as mentioned in the edit text it seems that vim thinks the cursor is in a different place when you're appending at the end of a line. Fixing it made the implmentation more logical anyway so no better.

Comment: when it reaches the beginning of the line, it starts gobbling up the lines above and the text in front of the cursor